# Rubyで浮動小数点数が何乗であるかを取得する方法が知りたい

Tags: ruby

Rubyで正負の浮動小数点数が10の何乗であるかを取得できるメソッドを作りたい（もしくはライブラリ等であれば知りたい）です．

無い場合は，以下のような仕様で作りたいのですが，方法がわかりません
どなたかご教授宜しくお願い致します．

<仕様>
メソッド名： getExpNum
引数　　　： 1つの実数
戻り値　　： べき乗の数字

<例>

```
num1 = -3.4556e5
p getExpNum(num1)  # => 5

num2 = 1.2956e-5
p getExpNum(num2)  # => -5
```

Comment: Ruby的には`-3.4556e5`と`-0.34556e6`は全く同じ値なんですが、どちらも`5`を返せば良いということで良いんでしょうか?

Comment: @OOPer さん　はい，浮動小数点数の数字そのままを返してもらいたいです．

Comment: 浮動小数点数は内部では2進数になっているので、「浮動小数点数の数字そのまま」では意味をなしません。整数部の値を`1`..`9`にした時の指数部(たとえば`1234.0`なら`3`を返す)と言うことで良いのでしょうか?

Comment: 単に（絶対値の） `Math.log10` なだけでは

Comment: @OOPer さん，意図が伝わりづらい説明で申し訳ありません．その解釈で問題ありません．

Comment: では、774RRさんの解釈で問題ないですね。回答として書いていただけるでしょう。

Comment: @OOPer，774RR さん，ありがとうございます．ご指摘の通りできました．ありがとうございます

Comment: 参考までに、BigDecimal クラスに [exponent method](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/BigDecimal/exponent) があるので、`BigDecimal(num1.to_s).exponent() - 1` などとしても宜しいかと。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

基数１０で表記したとき何桁になるか、であるなら絶対値を `Math.log10` して小数点以下を切り上げるとよいでしょう（ `+1` を忘れずに）。

１より小さい値に対しては `log10` が負数になるので、このときの処理はあなたの要望によって違う可能性があります（ `floor` なのか `ceil` なのか `0` に向かっての切りつめか）要望に応じた整数化を行ってください。